# Azure Traffic Manager for multiple web apps

Tags: azure, architecture, azure-traffic-manager

Hello I have 3 different web app. Each web app has a different application with a different endpoint. I need to replicate all of these app services in multiples region. My question is. Do I need to have one Traffic manager for each replication application?

The other alternative that I had was. I could have one traffic manager in front of all applications, and Behind the traffic manager but ahead of the all application for integrating all app service in a one,  I could have one API gateway. In that case, I suppose that I could have only one traffic manager instead of three.

Does somebody have one recommendation for this type of architecture?

Answer (score 1):

Azure traffic manager is designed as a global service,not bound to a location. If you have 3 webapps located in different regions, use one traffic manager to route all requests will be ok. This reference architecture will be helpful: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/architecture/reference-architectures/app-service-web-app/multi-region